# Asynchronous tests using jest and only callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I'm trying to implement some asynchronous tests using jest and only callbacks. I managed to make this code, which I hope is right (it passes the test):

```
test('Test the then() clause', function (done) {
    expect.assertions(1);
    const result = generate();
    new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            resolve(result);
        }, 100);
    }).then((data) => {
        expect(data).toBe(result);
        done();
    });
});
```

But I'm stuck trying to create a test when I expect to catch an error, just like so:

```
test('Test unhandled promise rejection', function (done) {
    expect.assertions(1);
    try {
        new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                reject('errorrrrr');
            }, 100);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        done();
    }
});
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: If you want to do this with a callback then simply get rid of the try/catch

```
test('Test unhandled promise rejection', function (done) {
    new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                reject('errorrrrr');
            }, 100);
    }).catch(() => {
      console.log(error);
      done();
    });
});
```

You need to await the promise, otherwise it doesn't throw

```
test('Test unhandled promise rejection', async function (done) {
    expect.assertions(1);
    try {
        await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                reject('errorrrrr');
            }, 100);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        done();
    }
});
```

So it's just plain easier (IMO) to skip the callbacks and use [resolves/rejects](https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#resolves--rejects)

```
test('Test unhandled promise rejection', async () => {
    await expect(new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                reject('errorrrrr');
            }, 100);
    }).rejects.toMatch('errorrrrr')
});
```

Comment: I understand this, but I don't want to use async and await. My real problem is implemented without promises, so asyn/await don't work. I provided a simple code 'simulating' my real problem. Thats why I'm using done().

Comment: @ClecioJung - edited. Don't use try/catch, but if you're real code doesn't use promises, I don't see how the simulated code you've provided is even relevant.